# onbeforeunload to rollback some actions

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, server-side, onbeforeunload

I have an onbeforeunload and it is working fine. However, I wanted a way to trigger my DB method to delete my existing item if the user choose to leave the page. How is it possible to detect the result as well as to trigger my DB method? My DB method is on the server-side.

Here is my javascript for the onbeforeunload:

```
    var showMsg = true;
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (showMsg) {
            return "You must publish your profile. Leaving this page will delete the profile information you have entered."
        }
    }
```